# Accidentally removed ubuntu-desktop and Unity when removing compiz, how do I get them back?

Tags: unity, compiz

When I was trying to reinstall compiz, first I tried to remove it and I think I have deleted my ubuntu-desktop and unity at the same time. I have tried to reinstall them but no use and now I'm stuck in a black screen after the Ubuntu logo. No desktop, no Unity, just a black screen and all I can do is reach the terminal through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

So if anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: what do you mean with "i have tried to reinstall" - what have you tried?
have you tried (in the terminal (alt+ctrl+f1)) an sudo apt-get install compiz and sudo apt-get install unity (if that package does not exist do a apt-cache search unity - maybe the package is named something like "unity8"

Answer (score 3):

Login into virtual console (ctrl+alt+F1) during the black screen appears,then run the below commands,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

After that run the below command to restart your pc,

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```